# Simple screen recorder and whatsapp web video format

Tags: screen, whatsapp

I have this problem, I am recording my screen using simple screen recorder in Ubuntu. The format is the default, which is mp4 ( .H264 ).

My problem is that when I open whats app web, and I try to attach a video to a message, the video does not show up on the list of available videos. If I select "All files" and send it anyway, it does not have a thumbnail when it reaches to other persons, and also, som people is able to reproduce it while some cant.

Whats the right video format I must choose for Whatsapp to recognize the video and send it properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can with below configs.

- Container **MP4**
- Video -> Codec: H.264

[image: Here is screenshot of that config]